# Open/Close a menu

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 2 headings which are `Administration` and `Market`

[image]

If I click on `Administration`, submenus are displayed (Portfolio and Corporate Action)

[image]

My problem is that if I now open the `Market` menu, the `Administration` section is still open.

[image]

I would like the user to be able to open just one menu.

```
<ul class="nav-links" *ngFor="let menu of menus; let i = index">
   <li [ngClass]="{ selected: selectedTab === menu.route }">
      <a routerLink="{{ menu.route }}" routerLinkActive="active" (click)="toggleMenu(i); selectedTab = menu.route">
      <i class="{{ menu.class }}"></i>
      <span class="links_name"> {{ menu.item }} </span>
      <i class="{{ menu.arrowDown }} iconArrow" *ngIf="selectedTab !== menu.route || !showSubmenu[i]"></i>
      <i class="{{ menu.arrowUp }} iconArrow " *ngIf="selectedTab === menu.route && showSubmenu[i]"></i>
      </a>
   </li>
   <ng-container *ngFor="let submenu of menu.submenus; let j = index">
      <li *ngIf="showSubmenu[i]">
         <a routerLink="{{ submenu.route }}">
         <i class="{{ submenu.class }}"></i>
         <span class="links_name"> {{ submenu.item }} </span>
         </a>
      </li>
   </ng-container>
</ul>
```

and

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

    selectedTab: string;

    showSubmenu: any[] = [];

    menus: any[] = [

        /* Administration */
        {
            class: 'bx bx-lock-alt',
            item: 'Administration',
            route: '/dashboard/administration',
            arrowDown: 'bx bx-chevron-down',
            arrowUp: 'bx bx-chevron-up',

            submenus: [{
                    class: 'bx bx-key',
                    item: 'Portfolio',
                    route: '/administration/portfolio',
                },
                {
                    class: 'bx bx-wallet',
                    item: 'Corporate Action',
                    route: '/administration/corporate-action',
                },
            ],
        },



        /* Market */
        {
            class: 'bx bx-chart',
            item: 'Market',
            route: '/dashboard/market',
            arrowDown: 'bx bx-chevron-down',
            arrowUp: 'bx bx-chevron-up',

            submenus: [{
                    class: 'bx bx-coin-stack',
                    item: 'Value',
                    route: '/market/value',
                },
                {
                    class: 'bx bx-line-chart',
                    item: 'Indice',
                    route: '/market/indice',
                },

            ],
        },

    ];

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {}


    toggleMenu(index: number) {
        this.showSubmenu[index] = !this.showSubmenu[index];
    }

}
```

The code is also [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-y82vk1?file=src/app/views/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

First get rid of showSubmenu, instead of this create a new property inside menus:

```
        {
            class: 'bx bx-lock-alt',
            item: 'Administration',
            route: '/dashboard/administration',
            arrowDown: 'bx bx-chevron-down',
            arrowUp: 'bx bx-chevron-up',
            isOpened: false // new property

        },
```

And in toggleMenu function firstly map the menus ad turn all isOpened to false, and change the last clicked menu items isOpened property to true like:
`menu[index].isOpened = true`